# Windows Server 2012 & Exchange Server 2013 CAL's

Tags: exchange, windows-server-2012, cal

Trying to build an Exchange server solution for a company and they want me to look into licensing for Windows. I'm going to be purchasing the necessary server licenses for Windows Server 2012 Standard and Microsoft Exchange 2013 Enterprise. I just have a few questions about the CAL's thing which seems like a complete ripoff to me.
How are CAL's tracked for both Windows Server and Exchange? Is it tied to Active Directory profiles?
What happens if I dont have the necessary CAL's for Windows Server? Will a client be denied access from Active Directory? Is there any enforcement for this? Also the same question for Exchange 2013 CAL's

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I just have a few questions about the CAL's thing which seems like a complete ripoff to me.

You're not going to get much sympathy for that here. It's how Microsoft chooses to license access to their products and as professional sysadmins, we do the professional thing and stay compliant with our licenses.

> How are CAL's tracked for both Windows Server and Exchange?

Honor system, except for RDS CALs. Those are enforced.

> Is it tied to Active Directory profiles?

No.

> What happens if I dont have the necessary CAL's for Windows Server?

Then you hope that you are never part of a license audit.

> Will a client be denied access from Active Directory?

No.

> Is there any enforcement for this?

Microsoft and various licensing partners occasionally conduct licensing audits. If you are non-compliant, you are generally given a chance to "settle up." If you don't you risk fines and/or a lawsuit.

> Also the same question for Exchange 2013 CAL's

Same as above.